# Mysql to find password is forgetten

Tags: mysql, passwords, mysql-workbench

I forgot MySql root password. How can I find it?

How can I back up database and import new database?

I tried to change root password and authority in user password, in this file;

> "c:/Program Data/MySql/MySql Server 5.6/data/mysql/user.frm"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpEwE.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mysql change forgotted password

```
0) shut down service mysql56

1) go to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
 (note that ProgramData is a hidden folder)

2) look for file my.ini, open it and add one line skip-grant-tables below [mysqld],
      save  [mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
3) start service mysql56

4) by right, you can access the database, and use the query below to update the password

update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root';
5) shun down the service again, remove the line skip-grant-tables save it, and start the service again. try to use the password you set to login.
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset the password
Follow these steps (can be helpful if you really forget your password and you can try it anytime, even if you're not in the situation at the moment):

1. Stop mysql

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   ```

or for other distro versions

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

2. Start MySQL in safe mode

   ```
   sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
   ```
3. Log into MySQL using root

   ```
   mysql -uroot
   ```
4. Select the MySQL database to use

   ```
   use mysql;
   ```
5. Reset the password

   ```
   update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
   ```
6. Flush the privileges

   ```
   flush privileges;
   ```
7. Restart the server

   ```
   quit
   ```
8. Stop and start the server again

ubuntu and debian

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

...

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

On CentOS and Fedora and RHEL

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
    ...
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

9. Login with new password

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

Type new password and enjoy your server again like nothing happened

taken from [mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/)

The [wiki](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html) also explains other ways to reset the password using a text file.